# MATLAB without display on a Linux server

Tags: matlab

I get this message when running some scripts using a remote Linux server running MATLAB (with `nodisplay` and `nosplash`), which is (I think) related to Java, but I was not able to find a solution after searching:

```
desktop is not supported because:
Swing is not currently available.
In file "/opt/MATLAB/R2012b/toolbox/matlab/general/desktop.m" (???), function "desktop" at line 20.
```

MATLAB version: 2012b

Machine: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Is it a warning or an error. Can you just ignore the message?

Comment: It is an error, no I can't ignore because it terminates the ongoing process...

Comment: Hmm, no idea. Try "-nodesktop"?

Comment: My understanding of the message is that Matlab tries to start the Desktop, which is written in Java and uses Swing components, but this fails. I don't know though why it would try to start the Desktop since you've given the "nodisplay" option.

Comment: Try `-nojvm -nodisplay -nodesktop`.

Comment: with `-nojvm` the error changes to `desktop is not supported because:
Java is not currently available.` So it is now Java not available, instead of Swing.

Comment: Arman: `-nodesktop`?

Comment: Thank you @A.Donda . Damn my ignorant mind! if you want please add your response below so that I can select it as the best response.

Comment: @Arman, well, actually `-nodisplay` should have taken care of this, so the ignorance is on the side of Matlab. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the message is that Matlab tries to start the Desktop, which is written in Java and uses Swing components, but this fails. I don't know though why it would try to start the Desktop since you've given the `-nodisplay` option.

Try to use the `-nodesktop` option additionally.